# Почему PhpStorm не определяет переменные для проекта на joomla или называет их классами?

Tags: phpstorm

[image: Multiple definitions exist for class JText]

> Multiple definitions exist for class JText The inspection can produce
>   two types of warnings: Undefined class: Declaration of referenced
>   class is not found in built-in library and project files. Multiple
>   declarations: this version of IDE *will* have problems with
>   completion, member resolution and inheritance analysis for all classes
>   that have multiple definitions in project files (regardless of
>   includes).

ИЛИ
[image: Variable 'tg' might have not been defined]

> Variable  'tg' might have not been defined The inspection can produce
>   two types of warnings: The definition of the variable can not be found
>   anywhere. ("Undefined variable") There are one or more paths to reach
>   the line with the variable usage without defining it. ("Variable might
>   have not been defined")  All variables from files that contain
>   'include' or 'require' are considered as defined if the option "Ignore
>   'include' and 'require' statements" is disabled.  The inspection is
>   enabled for global space by default.

Программа это объясняет отсутствием виденья содержимого include и require.

Для статических переменных, вроде JText:: трудно найти концы в дереве каталога,  но почему не определена переменная tg, которая была  создана несколько строк выше, в этом же файле, это видно на втором эскизе. Язык PHP 7.0.

И как отключить опцию «Ignore» include и require?

Comment: потому что это не чистый PHP и он не понимает. нужно скачать плагин https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8288-joomla-support

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо  Jurij Jazdanov за ответ. Правда разобраться какая мне  нужна  версия плагина так и не удалось, а метод тыка не дал результата.
Но уже одно название плагина говорит за себя. Установила по ссылке File > Settings > Plugins >   Joomla! Support (в поиске).